# R - Building a dataframe using Country,continent, latitude and longitude

Tags: r, geocoding

I have a dataframe that has a list of countries on one column and I am looking to get the Continent Name, Latitude and Longitude of that country.

For example,

```
df <- data.frame(CountryName = c("Austria", "Czech Republic", "Finland"))
```

I am looking to get a dataframe that has Continent, latitude and longitude with it.

```
library(countrycode)
library(geocode)

df$continent <- as.factor(countrycode(sourcevar = df[, "CountryName"], origin = "country.name", destination = "continent"))
```

So, I have got the Continent in my dataframe now.

`geocode("Austria")` returns lat and long in R. 
Can you guide me in getting that inside the Dataframe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you can call `geocode()` from `ggmap` (I know no package `geocode`) for all countries at once and use `cbind` like this:

```
cbind(df, ggmap::geocode(as.character(df[, "CountryName"]), force = FALSE))
# Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Austria&sensor=false
# Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Czech%20Republic&sensor=false
# Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Finland&sensor=false
#      CountryName continent      lon      lat
# 1        Austria    Europe 14.55007 47.51623
# 2 Czech Republic    Europe 15.47296 49.81749
# 3        Finland    Europe 25.74815 61.92411
```

However, one quite often gets warning messages concerning OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. In order to solve that one probably needs an API key, c.f. [Getting OVER QUERY LIMIT after one request with geocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175529/getting-over-query-limit-after-one-request-with-geocode).

Comment: Yes, and how do we get that problem (OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) solved.

Answer (score 0):

Get past the "OVER QUERY LIMIT" problem by signing up for your own Google API key: [Google API sign-up](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key)

See the related stack-overflow question: [stackoverflow.com/questions/36175529](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175529/getting-over-query-limit-after-one-request-with-geocode)