# Drawing map of Hong Kong

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I would like to draw a map of Hong Kong basemap using R but it failed. Below is the code and the error R returns:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

map <- get_map(location = "Hong Kong", zoom = 10, scale = 2, maptype = "roadmap", 
               source = "google", force = ifelse(source == "google", TRUE, TRUE), 
               messaging = FALSE, urlonly = FALSE, filename = "ggmapTemp", 
               crop = TRUE, color = "color", language = "en-EN", api_key)
```

> Error in data.frame(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2]) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1 In addition: Warning message: geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Hong Kong"

The above coding is fine for taiwan, china and state, don't know why it failed for Hong Kong.

Comment: have you tried other cities like Beijing, Rome or New York?

Comment: I am failing to replicate this error. The output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Trwj.png

Comment: Is that the full error message or do you get: `Error in data.frame(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
In addition: Warning message:
geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Hong Kong" `. Normally this error occurs when you are over the query limit for the Google Maps API

Comment: @Jimbou yes, and failed as well....

Comment: @MikeyHarper May I know how did you get the output? ; yes I got the over query limit as well

Comment: It worked fine for me. I haven't used `ggmap` in a few months so I am far from the query limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting OVER QUERY LIMIT after one request with geocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175529/getting-over-query-limit-after-one-request-with-geocode)

Comment: The key issue here is the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, which the question above should help explain.

Comment: I checked with geocodeQueryCheck() as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175529/getting-over-query-limit-after-one-request-with-geocode 
and it returns there are 2467 geocoding queries remaining

Comment: While the results for city names keeps failing, it worked everytime when i changed the location to a country name.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2018, `getmap()` only works with a registered and billing-activated Google Maps API key and longitude / latitude coordinates.

See [more info and a step-by-step tutorial](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/51) here.