# multiple sites on a ggplot2 map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot all my sites on a ggplot map. I have 5 locations with multiple sites per location, but when I try to plot all my sites, it  only displays one point per location instead of one point per site. I have 34 sites and 5 locations so I need a map with 34 points instead of 5! Any help would be super appreciated! Thanks so so much

These are the data with y and x as my long and lat.

> `Location     PAR          y           x
>   Guam    GFA     201.09952   144.8786111 13.495
>   Guam    GFA2    179.04171   144.6597222 13.41638889
>   Guam    GFA3    67.66379    144.2761111 13.47333333
>   Guam    GFB1    201.09952   144.7105556 13.31416667
>   Guam    GFB2    179.04171   144.655     13.50194444
>   Guam    GFB3    67.66379    144.8697222 13.37472222`

I need to plot all my 6 sites for Guam. This is the code I am using and the final output

```
map.world <- map_data(map="world")
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="none")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=map.world, map=map.world, aes(map_id=region, x=long, y=lat), fill="white", colour="black", size=0.25) + theme_bw()
gg

par<-read.csv("parmap.csv", header=T)
head(par)
g<-gg+ geom_polygon() + 
  geom_point(data=par, aes(x = y, y = x, color=PAR)) +theme_minimal()
g
```

[image: MAP]

Comment: @Sathish thanks so much for editing my code

Comment: Using the example data you posted, all six sites are plotted. They're just so close together that the points appear on top of each other when you plot the full world map.

Comment: Oh thanks so much! So how should edit to show the sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to zoom your map near point of interest i.e. 'Guam' in this case.

One approach could be like below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

#get the map
center = paste(min(df$lat)+(max(df$lat)-min(df$lat))/2, 
               min(df$lon)+(max(df$lon)-min(df$lon))/2, sep=" ")
map <- get_map(location = center, maptype = "roadmap", zoom = 8, source = "google", color="bw")
p <- ggmap(map)

#plot points on the map
plt <- p +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = PAR)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10)) +
  theme_minimal()
plt
```

**Update:** I have slightly modified your sample data. You can notice that I have added one more location in sample data to plot all 7 points (i.e. 6 sites for one location and 1 site for another location) on the map.

**Output plot is:**
[image]

Note: In case you get `geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175529/getting-over-query-limit-after-one-request-with-geocode) link might be helpful.

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Location = c("Guam", "Guam", "Guam", "Guam", "Guam", 
"Guam", "N_Mariana_Islands"), sites = c("GFA", "GFA2", "GFA3", 
"GFB1", "GFB2", "GFB3", "NMI1"), PAR = c(201.09952, 179.04171, 
67.66379, 201.09952, 179.04171, 67.66379, 100), lon = c(144.8786111, 
144.6597222, 144.2761111, 144.7105556, 144.655, 144.8697222, 
145.192522), lat = c(13.495, 13.41638889, 13.47333333, 13.31416667, 
13.50194444, 13.37472222, 14.150817)), .Names = c("Location", 
"sites", "PAR", "lon", "lat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
#           Location sites       PAR      lon      lat
#1              Guam   GFA 201.09952 144.8786 13.49500
#2              Guam  GFA2 179.04171 144.6597 13.41639
#3              Guam  GFA3  67.66379 144.2761 13.47333
#4              Guam  GFB1 201.09952 144.7106 13.31417
#5              Guam  GFB2 179.04171 144.6550 13.50194
#6              Guam  GFB3  67.66379 144.8697 13.37472
#7 N_Mariana_Islands  NMI1 100.00000 145.1925 14.15082
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Prem! GF are actually my sites! so it keeps coloring the points by sites and not by PAR... and it would not let me plot the sites from other locations..sorry I am very new to this

Comment: how could I eventually zoom in the map I created to show all my points? Thank you