# ggmap geocode function returning NA's

Tags: r, ggmap

I have a dataset of the locations of various Tim Horton coffee shops within the USA.  I applied the mutate_geocode() function to my dataset that contains 740 rows to get the latlon coordinates.  I was able to successfully geocode 591 rows and returned NA's in 149 rows.

My geocode function code looks like this:

```
newdataset <- mutate_geocode(dataset, fullAddress, source = "google")
```

A sample/subset csv of the results that are NA are below

```
fullAddress,lon,lat
"109 Bennett Dr , Caribou , ME 4736",NA,NA
"1201 S Main St , Ann Arbor , MI 48104",NA,NA
"2679 Ann Arbor Saline Rd , Ann Arbor , MI 48103",NA,NA
```

I have gone through many of my NA's and can't figure out why the output of mutate_geocode() would be NA.  If I copy paste the addresses into google maps I get the result I am looking for.  The source of the geocode data comes from Google!  I was going to ignore this and move on with the locations that were successfully geocoded but I can't/don't want to let this go.  Does anyone have any insight why the geocode function is behaving this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the spaces before the commas might help:

```
dataset <- read.table(text ="fullAddress
'109 Bennett Dr, Caribou, ME 4736'
'1201 S Main St, Ann Arbor, MI 48104'
'2679 Ann Arbor Saline Rd, Ann Arbor, MI 48103'",
stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, quote = "'", sep = ",")
```

If I call `mutate_geocode()` on the first row I get the desired results:

```
                       fullAddress      lon      lat
1 109 Bennett Dr, Caribou, ME 4736 -68.0041 46.86837
```

If you keep getting `geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` errors, then check this other question: [Getting OVER QUERY LIMIT after one request with geocode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36175529/2699660)